# node-webkit screen flicker

Tags: html, angularjs, node-webkit, tidesdk

I am trying to repurpose an old .exe I made using TideSDK a couple years ago. I have replaced the relevent TideSDK code with node-webkit code, and everything seems to be working as expected. With one exception, the original (TideSDK .exe) used multiple html pages with simple anchor tags to change the view. When I use this method with node-webkit the screen flickers between views (it displays whatever programs are running in the background for maybe ~200ms - 300ms). Does anybody know a solution to fix this? I could re-build as a single page app using angularjs - but would prefer if I could keep the structure I have as time is an issue.

I would really appreciate an input on this.

Edit:
here is a link the the .nw file, if you put this in you you node webkit folder and run it you can see the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h53kyyidi4qslr/test.nw?dl=0

I didn't want to package it as an exe so you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had deal with that problem in another way. I had to use several views for my GUI on my app and the way i did it is to read the view and store it on memory, so it could be available later on. I had used jQuery on my project and it does not run anything on background unless I require the action.

what i do is:

1. an array with the views to use, and store them into an array
2. in runtime, when I require a view, I just call it and place the HTML code of that view into the app.

as you can see, it shouldn't create a big problem, but in my side, it is very reliable  and safe.